# LinearLayout unable to add view on some devices

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to add some views(mostly TextView) to LinearLayout but it works only on some devices. I've tested this code on Samsung Galaxy S5, Lenovo Tab2 and Samsung Galaxy S9. Only S5 worked with this code and it can add view to LinearLayout. the other ones can't add. What is the problem with this codes? Is there any problem with xml codes?

Thanks in advance

Java code:

```
lay.addView(getContentView(this, "Hello", Color.RED));
,,,
,,,
public TextView getContentView(Context mContext, String str, int color) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        String time = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" +  (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText(time + " " + str);
        textView.setTextColor(color);
        return textView;
    }
```

xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Please set layout params of textview. textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams

Comment: First change `layContainer` height to `wrap_content`. Also set layout params and gravity for textView

Comment: @ jay shah Thanks, I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set layout params to textview you created

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```